# wp_mail issue with sending PDF

Tags: wp-mail, pdf

I have a problem with `wp_mail` and sending a PDF. The code below occasionally works and when it does, you can only see the message content within the iPhone, and not Yahoo or Gmail.

```
function submit_paycerts( $post_id ) {
    $status          = get_field( 'paycert_status', $post_id );
    $certName        = get_field( 'paycert_name', $post_id );
    $certaddress     = get_field( 'paycert_address', $post_id );
    $certPostcode    = get_field( 'paycert_postcode', $post_id );
    $certAccount     = get_field( 'paycert_account', $post_id );
    $certPayMethod  = get_field( 'paycert_payment_method', $post_id );
    $weekEnding      = get_field( 'paycert_week_ending', $post_id );
    $certPayRate     = get_field( 'paycert_pay_rate', $post_id );
    $certEmail   = get_field( 'paycert_email', $post_id );
    $certUTR         = get_field( 'paycert_utr', $post_id );
    $certTaxStat     = get_field( 'paycert_tax_status', $post_id );
    $certVer         = get_field( 'paycert_verification_date', $post_id );
    $certExp         = get_field( 'paycert_expiry_date', $post_id );
    $certTotalHours = get_field( 'paycert_total_hours', $post_id );
    $cert4th         = get_field( 'paycert_fourth_meter', $post_id );
    $cert5th         = get_field( 'paycert_fifth_meter', $post_id );
    $cert6th         = get_field( 'paycert_sixth_meter', $post_id );
    $certTotalOn     = get_field( 'paycert_total_oncall', $post_id );
    $certTotalStand = get_field( 'paycert_standby', $post_id );
    $certStandWeek  = get_field( 'paycert_standby_weekend', $post_id );
    $certTotal   = get_field( 'paycert_total', $post_id );
    $certBonus   = get_field( 'paycert_bonus', $post_id );  
    $certAdd         = get_field( 'paycert_additions', $post_id );
    $certDeduct      = get_field( 'paycert_deductions', $post_id );
    $certExp         = get_field( 'paycert_expenses', $post_id );
    $certUTRLess     = get_field( 'less_cis_tax', $post_id );
    $certUTRTotal    = get_field( 'paycert_total_paid', $post_id );
    $certNote        = get_field( 'paycert_bonus_note', $post_id );

    $pdf = new FPDF( 'P','mm','A4' );
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->AddFont( 'Courier', '', 'courier.php' );
    $pdf->SetFont( 'courier', '', 14 );
    $pdf->Cell( 40, 10, 'Name: ' . $certName );
    $pdf->Cell( 40, 40, 'Address: ' . $certaddress . ', ' . $certPostcode );

    // email stuff (change data below)
    $to = $certEmail;

    $subj = 'Payment Certification - ' . $weekEnding;
    $headers = array( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );
    $headers[] = 'From: AES Admin <admin@smileapps.uk>';

    $message = "<p>Please find your Payment Certification attached.</p>";

    // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5( time() );

    // carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
    $eol = PHP_EOL;

    // attachment name
    $filename = "PaymentCertification.pdf";

    // encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
    $pdfdoc = $pdf->Output( "", "S" );
    $attachment = chunk_split( base64_encode( $pdfdoc ) );

    // main header
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol; 
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"";

    // no more headers after this, we start the body! //
    $body  = "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol . $eol;

    // message
    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
    $body .= $message . $eol;

    // attachment
    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol; 
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
    $body .= $attachment . $eol;
    $body .= "--" . $separator . "--"; 

    // send message
    if ( $status == 'Final' ) {
        wp_mail( $to, $subj, $body, $headers );
    } elseif ( $status == 'Draft' ) {
        // 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attaching the attachments to body content. Pass it as separate parameter. Like the below one.

```
      @wp_mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers,$mail_attachment);
```

I guess it solves your problem.